# How can I use a pandas-dataframe generated inside one class of mine in a QtableView?

Tags: python, pandas, class, pyqt5

Good afternoon, I'm trying to see a pandas dataframe as a QTableView. In the code below there is an example of a dataframe that i'm working on, it's just a sample, a draft, at the present it should generate a 4x13 dataframa full of NaN values, it's ok.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QAbstractTableModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication

import sys


class metodos_se(QObject):

    fs: float = 2

    def __init__(self, _dados, _fluxo):
        super().__init__()

        self.dados = _dados
        self.fluxo = _fluxo
        self.controle()

    def controle(self):

        self.fluxo[0].btn.clicked.connect(self.fluxo[0].close)

    def _aoki_velloso(self):

        self.num_son = int(self.fluxo[0].num_son.text())

        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 4)
        self.tab = pd.DataFrame(index=(0, 1, 2, 3),
                           columns=['Prof_m', 'Nspt', 'F1', 'K_kN/cm²',
                           'Ap_cm²', 'Pp_kN', 'F2', 'K_kN/cm²', 'α',
                           'Perim_cm', 'Pl, unit._kN', 'Pl, acum._kN', 'Pr_kN'])
        self.tab['Prof_m'] = (0, 1, 2, 4)
        self.tab['Nspt'] = (1, 2, 3, 4)
        self.tab['Nspt'] = self.tab['Nspt'].apply(lambda x: x + 1)


class result_tab(QAbstractTableModel, metodos_se):

    def __init__(self, _data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)

        self.metodos_se = _data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.metodos_se.tab.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.metodos_se.tab.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self.metodos_se.tab.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def header_data(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.metodos_se.tab.columns[col]
        return None


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = result_tab([])
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(800, 600)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, this dataframe is generated within a class, I tried to pass my class into this model, but to no success,

```
class result_tab(QAbstractTableModel, metodos_se):
```

when I run this I get no errors, but the compiler closes itself.

ps. I hope this piece of code fits as a MRE

Comment: Your code is very confusing. First of all, it's not clear why you're subclassing `metodos_se` from QObject, nor why you're trying multiple inheritance with that, especially considering that you're not even calling the `__init__` for the other inherited class. That said, the `self.metodos_se` you're using in the `result_tab` class is the data you're passing as argument (which is an empty list, in your example). Run your code in a terminal/prompt and you'll see the error.

Comment: hi @musicamante, I managed to solve the problem, your comment actually helped me, I think it was more of an organizational matter!! tnx!!